# debugging windows applications - event viewer in Win 7 32 bit

Tags: windows, snap-in

Been trying for days now to get around the  MMC snap-in failed to create or initialize error for the Event Viewer. I have tried sfc /scannow, regsvr32, Dependency Walker, Win 7 repair disk, chkdsk, dumpbin /dependents and lately trying to install the Windows SDK tools without success. But none of these utilities are helping. The reason for the event viewer is due to a problem with the IIS Manager, installs but will not run. I can not find anything missing or corrupted and the registry key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns\FX:{b05566ad-fe9c-4363-be05-7a4cbb7cb510} with key = moduleName value = EventViewer.dll.

C:\Windows\winsxs\msil_eventviewer_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_a7c7be940756e915>regsvr32 eventviewer.dll

result:
The module eventviewer.dll was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, does `DllRegisterServer` exist? Of course `regsvr32` will fail if it's missing. Also, your question is _very_ unclear. I don't even know where to start.

Comment: My basic problem that started all this is the need for some details due to the issue I am having with the IIS Manager. It would install but did not run, no error messages and inetmgr.exe does not show in running processes of the Task Manager. So then tried the Event Viewer and started getting these errors on how the MMC snap-in could not be created. I then tried the mmc.exe to add the Event Viewer and then the MMC snap-in initialization error showed. So this lead me to regsvr32.exe and found it works for some of the dlls like evr.dll but not others like eventviewer.dll.

Comment: Ok, you're not programming yourself. That explains why I couldn't find a programming question here. Move ==> ServerFault